# Call a JS function on any link click inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, href

Scenario:

An iframe is loading a page with many different hyperlinks.

```
<iframe id=output>
    <a href="somedomain1.com"> click here </a>
    <a href="somedomain2.com"> click here </a>
    <a href="somedomain3.com"> click here </a>
</iframe>
```

I am aware that I cannot append `onclick="jsfunction()"` on a hyperlink inside an iframe.

But is there any way to call a JS function on any link click inside an iframe?

Edit:
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o6tfv84p/)

Comment: can you share your html code ?

Comment: post the full code, or post it on fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('output');
const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframeDoc.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('click inside iframe')
    if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey) return;
    if (e.defaultPrevented) return;
    // ensure link
    // use shadow dom when available
    var el = e.path ? e.path[0] : e.target;

    while (el && 'A' !== el.nodeName) el = el.parentNode;
    if (!el || 'A' !== el.nodeName) return;

    console.log('click a tag inside iframe')
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/17o093ov/2/

Please be aware that this only works if the iframe has the same origin as the parent page. Otherwise accessing `contentDocument` will be blocked by browser for security matters.

Comment: That works. But how to capture the clicks only of hyperlink? I mean only <a> tags clicks

Comment: I updated my answer to include the check for `a` tag click. But for some `a` tags it will not work, because the page already has event handlers on those tags and prevent my code to work. You could try click on `Sign In` link

Comment: Awesome Thanks :)